# aligning cards after filter function

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using javascript to filter between my cards. It works fine, except that I can't align the filtered card to the top left corner. It remains in the same column where it was (and sametimes in the same row aswell). Here's an example:
[wrong](https://i.gyazo.com/e24e4acad5e0aac7006c20a2ebf4e8fa.png)
And this is what I want:
[good](https://i.gyazo.com/09f7d97b28029a6f5c706ae214da63c4.png)

My code:

```
    function myFunction() {
      var input, filter, cards, cardContainer, title, i;
      input = document.getElementById("myFilter");
      filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
      cardContainer = document.getElementById("myItems");
      cards = cardContainer.getElementsByClassName("card");

      for (i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
        title = cards[i].querySelector(".card-body h4.card-category");
        if (title.innerText.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          cards[i].style.display = "";

        } else {
          cards[i].style.display = "none";

        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: you need css not javascript

Comment: filter with css?

Comment: you main title says alingnin cards AFTER filter meaning you want the correct positioning, what does this have to do with js?

Comment: I guess I should set it inside of js.

Comment: Hello Kristof, welcome on board :)
Usually, as Eugen noted, the look and the placement of html elements is the function of css not js. Yes it could happen that the drawing of an element be based on some conditions (javascript), however still it is still your css classes, direction (rtl, ltr) layers.. that control how would the html element would be rendered in the page
Again, in your case, the solution is not in js
Best of luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just figured it out. The problem was with this line:

`cards = cardContainer.getElementsByClassName("card");`

I changed it to

```
cards = cardContainer.getElementsByClassName("col-md-4");
```

because my card class was inside col-md-4 class and it couldn't set it's display attribute.